# String that is altered when a button is pressed is nil when the string needs to be passed to the next ViewController with prepareForSegue()

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

In my app there are different buttons that alter the same string but set it to different things depending on which button is pressed. I need this string, once altered based on the button pressed, to be passed to my next view controller. The problem is that in my prepareForSegue() method I have noticed that the string is showing up as nil. How do I get this to work so that the altered string is what is passed to the next ViewController? I feel as if the prepareForSegue is called too early if the string is nil at that point.

Here is my prepareForSegue:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    InfoViewController *ivc = [segue destinationViewController];
    if (_stringText != nil)
        ivc.viewText = _stringText;
}
```

So with this code I can clearly tell if _stringText is nil.

An example of a button press:

```
- (IBAction)time1Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self pullInfo:(1)];
}
```

Once the button is clicked it calls pullInfo (I shortened it to make this quicker):

```
- (void) pullInfo: (int) page
{
    NSError *err;
    NSURL *url = nil;

    if (page == 1)
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurltothetextfile"];

    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentOfURL:url];
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:htmlData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

    if (err != nil)
        printf("Error retrieving text");
    else
        _stringText = attrString;
}
```

Comment: You've verified `err` is nil?

Comment: @i_am_jorf Yes I have verified that err is nil.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `time1Clicked:` and `prepareForSegue:sender:`, are they hit in the order you would expect?

Comment: Please consider checking that your pullInfo method is working properly, placing the call [self pullInfo:1] to viewDidLoad method and checking the _stringText

Comment: @AlexanderKostiev If I change the second view controller to be under the original ViewController class and then do as you said then I get the string just fine. It is not being passed over correctly for some reason.